# Rails many-to-many associations on single-table-inheritance child models with join tables

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, inheritance, relational-database

I have a `Keyword` class that has multiple different categories/types through STI, as described below

```
class Keyword < ApplicationRecord
end

class Keyword1 < Keyword
end

class Keyword2 < Keyword
end

class Keyword3 < Keyword
end
```

I then have a `User` class. Each `User` should have many `Keyword1s`, `Keyword2s`, and `Keyword3s`. How do I set up this many-to-many relationship such that I can query for things like `user.keyword1s` instead of `user.keyword.where(type: "keyword1")` or something? Is it possible to have a single `UserKeyword` join table while still being able to select certain types easily (like maybe defining scopes on the parent `Keyword` class such that I can query for `user.keywords.keyword1s` or something)?

What is the best design to use here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly in the `has_many` relations defined in your `User` class

```rb
has_many :keyword1, class_name: 'Keyword1'
has_many :keyword2, class_name: 'Keyword2'
```

You can also use scopes for more fancy things

```rb
has_many :keyword1 -> { where(type: 'keyword1') }, class_name: 'Keyword'
has_many :keyword2 -> { where(type: 'keyword2') }, class_name: 'Keyword'
```

Comment: How does this work with my UserKeyword join table? does it have to be a `has_many through` statement?